# systemd-networkd - how to force new configuration without reboot?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

On my Arch box, I had a network bridge. The goal was to remove the bridge and to only use the network adapter not bridged. In order to do so, I removed all the *.netdev and *.network configuration files under `/etc/systemd/network` and replaced them with one simple file:

```
/etc/systemd/network/lan.network
--------------------------------
[Match]
eno*

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

I then restarted the network service using `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`, assuming this would leave me just with the `lo` and the `eno*` interface. Unfortunately, though, this had no effect. A quick look at `ip link` still showed the bridge interface up and active.

Because uptime in this particular case is not crucial, I just rebooted the machine which solved the problem. Still, I'd like to think that reboots should not be necessary for this kind of thing. What did I miss to do?

Comment: v244 has `networkctl reload` and `reconfigure` [@github.com/systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6654#issuecomment-568127537)

Answer (score 14):

If your bridge master interface is still up then its bound slave interfaces will remain bound even if new configurations are discovered for them in the meanwhile. So just lose the bridge.

```
ip link set down br0
ip link del dev br0
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Wouldn't I lose network access in the process?

Comment: @vic - if your network access is routed through a bridge to which you've bound your nic then yes, i expect so. i cant think of a simple way to do otherwise, and the complicated ways i can think of are only half-baked and involve temporary hold-over virtual nics and in-kernel netfilter duping of all packets on the dev. ugly and silly. either that or time-travel. maybe theres another way, but you wont learn it of me. anyway, network is only lost following the first command and afterward restored following the third. probably less dt than a reboot.

Comment: @vic I know I'm late to the party, but one way could be to chain the commands together in a single line, such as `ip link set down br0 && ip link del dev br0 && systemctl restart systemd-networkd`. Your connection may drop, at least momentarily, but the host's networking service should be back online and you can always create a new SSH session as long as you know the IP address you'll be getting after restarting it.

Comment: Use a semicolon, not `&&` to chain these commands. If one fails, it still may reconfigure the network connection in a usable way so you don't have to get up and visit the server...

Comment: For me `ip link del dev enp129s0f0` says `Operation not supported`

Comment: Remember to run those commands as root (aka `sudo ...`)

Comment: @Hi-Angel `ip link del` only removes virtual interfaces (like aliases or bridges). The unaliased `enp` usually is a physical interface.  So to remove it, you must physically remove it instead.  If the bus supports removing devices using software control (like USB), this can usually be archived trough the `/sys` tree somehow.